# How to push inside Json Object using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

i'm tryink to push an object inside a json object, but it gives me a duplicated json object, i will expalin:
heres my html:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 40% !important;" placeholder="Nom" class="input-sm"  ng-model="company.link.nom"  />
<input type="text" style="width: 40% !important;" placeholder="Lien" class="input-sm"  ng-model="company.link.value"  />
<a class="btn btn-wide btn-primary" ng-click="company.addExternalLinktoGrid()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Ajouter </a>
```

here is `addExternalLinktoGrid` function:

```
var linkJsonObj = [];
var cp=1;
company.addExternalLinktoGrid = function() {
  company.link.id=cp;
  currentObj.push(company.link);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(company.link));
  linkJsonObj.push(company.link);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(linkJsonObj));
  cp++;
}
```

For example, lets assume we add new object: `company.link.nom="toto"` and `company.link.value="titi"`, in this case `linkJsonObj` print:

```
[{"nom":"toto","value":"titi","id":1}]
```

lets add the second object `company.link.nom="momo"` and `company.link.value="mimi"`, in this case `linkJsonObj` print:

```
[{"nom":"momo","value":"mimi","id":2},
 {"nom":"momo","value":"mimi","id":2}]
```

This is what I got, I don't know why? but the expected behaviour is:

```
[{"nom":"toto","value":"titi","id":1},
 {"nom":"momo","value":"mimi","id":2}]
```

can anyone help please?

Comment: You use the `cp` as a closure, so you got the latest one values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

company.link in an object and if you push this object to an array it is passed by reference. If you overwrite the values of this object it will be overwritten in your array. What you need is to copy the object (values). If you push it multiple times to an array the array will contain multiple references to the same object.

```
var newObject = {
  nom: company.link.nom,
  value: company.link.value,
  id: cp
}
linkJsonObj.push(newObject);
```

Comment: even though i delete cp..it still gives me the same error